# "Column 'option_type_id' cannot be null..."

Tags: mysql, sql, magento

I'm writing an sql script and the end of the script this error appears.

"Column 'option_type_id' cannot be null"

```
SET @valor = 10, @op1 := @valor * 2 - 1, @op2 := @valor * 2;
...
INSERT INTO `magento`.`catalog_product_option_type_title`
 (`option_type_title_id`, `option_type_id`, `store_id`, `title`)
VALUES (@op1, @op1, '0', 'DIREITO');

INSERT INTO `magento`.`catalog_product_option_type_title`
 (`option_type_title_id`, `option_type_id`, `store_id`, `title`)
VALUES (@op2, @op2, '0', 'ESQUERDO');

INSERT INTO `magento`.`catalog_product_option_type_price`
 (`option_type_price_id`, `option_type_id`, `store_id`, `price`, `price_type`)
VALUES (@op1, @op1, '0', '0.0000', 'fixed');

INSERT INTO `magento`.`catalog_product_option_type_price`
 (`option_type_price_id`, `option_type_id`, `store_id`, `price`, `price_type`)
VALUES (@op2, @op2, '0', '0.0000', 'fixed');
```

I already test the other entries and works fine but these entries fail.
Please, help me. Thank you very much!

Comment: Apparently you can set variables with either `=` or `:=` so I have deleted my answer. You could try separating the first line into three SET commands in case that makes a difference.. I assume you are running the script in one session. Also double check to make sure you have not reset the variables and the values you want (not `null`) are in the other tables where you think it succeeded.

Comment: Arth, you made it! 
The problem is to separate the SET into three independent sets.
Now, all the script works. Thank you very much!

Comment: Happy to help, I have moved my comment to an answer and explained it.. kindly accept it! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently you can set variables with either `=` or `:=` so I have deleted my other answer.

You need to separate the first line into two SET commands:

```
SET @valor := 10;
SET @op1 := @valor * 2 - 1,@op2 := @valor * 2;
```

In the one liner `@valor` isn't set before the other two assignments so is `null` for those.

Any simple arithmetic on null in MySQL returns null, so `@op1` and `@op2` are set to `null`.

The other statements in the script will have inserted `null` for `@op1` and `@op2`, but `10` for `@valor`.